# How can I print the Students info?

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, getter-setter

Is there a way I can print my students with the information provided?
I created a service class with all the information about the course, where I wish to input my students info on a very simple way.

student class:

```
public class student {

    //Fields
    private static String classNumber = "264";
    private static String className = "Transfiguration";
    private static String instructor = "Professor McGonagall";

    private int studentId;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String email;

    //Getters and setters

    static String getClassNumber(){
        return (classNumber);
    }
    static String getClassName(){
        return (className);
    }
    static String getInstructor(){
        return (instructor);
    }
    static void setClassName(String name){
        className = name;
    }

    int getStudentId(){
        return (studentId);
    }
    String getFirstName(){
        return (firstname);
    }
    String getLastName(){
        return (lastname);
    }
    String getAddress(){
        return (address);
    }
    String getCity(){
        return (city);
    }
    String getState(){
        return (state);
    }
    String getEmail(){
        return (email);
    }
    void setFirstName(String first) {
        this.firstname = first;
    }
    void setLastName(String last) {
        this.lastname = last;
    }
    void setAddress(String rua) {
        this.address = rua;
    }
    void setCity(String cidade) {
        this.city = cidade;
    }
    void setEmail(Sring correio) {
        this.email = correio;
     }
     //Contructors
    student(String la) {
        this.firstname = first;
        this.lastname = last;
        this.studentId += 1000;
    }
    student(String la, int id, String first, String last, String rua, String cidade, String correio) {

        this(la);

        this.address = rua;
        this.city = cidade;
        this.email = correio;

     }

    public String toString() {
        String data = "Course: " + classNumber + " " + className + 
                    "\t instructor: " + instructor + 
                    "\t Student Number: " + id + 
                    "\t Student Name: "  + firstname + " " + lastname + 
                    "\t Address: " + rua + cidade + 
                    "\t Email: " + correio;
        return (data);            
    }

}
```

studentTest class:

```
public class studentTest {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        System.out.println("Course: " + student.getClassNumber() + student.getClassName());

        student a = new student("Kakashi", "Hatake", "W 69th st", "NY", "khsensei@ninja.com");
        student b = new student("Albus", "Dumbledore", "W 116th st", "NY", "princip-al@hogwarts.com" );
        student c = new student("Hyuk", "Jang", "321 Maple St", "NJ", "jh@actors.com");
        student d = new student("Michael", "Jackson", "543 thriller st", "NY", "mj@singer.com");
        student e = new student("Hamilton", "Alexander", "E 86th st", "NY", "justyouwait@broadway.com");

        String fname = a.firstname;
        System.out.println("First Name: " + fname);

        System.out.println(a.toString());
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

What I wish to do is print all the information on their proper place, however I must have forgotten something pretty serious that I'm getting error messages. Are the students info linked properly to the first class?

--

A few of the error messages I get:
"student.java:114: error: class studentTest is public, should be declared in a file named studentTest.java" - for this one, I've tried before and I can put both classes on the same file, why wouldn't be working now?

Some symbols can't be found:

*symbol: variable first
location: class student
student.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
             this.lastname = last;*

the same also happens with the variables *id, last, rua, cidade,* and *correio*.

there's also an error about the constructor
     *constructor student.student(String) is no applicable
           (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
     constructor student.student(String, int, String, String, String, String) is no applicable
student.java:124 error: no suitable constructor found for student (String, String...)*

Comment: What error messages?  Those might help.

Comment: are you sure that the constructors are true? especially first constructor.

Comment: @duffymo I have added a few error messages to the post

Comment: You have to learn how to interpret compiler error messages if you intend to write Java. Believe the compiler. You can’t make progress if you insist that all is well.

Comment: Hint: don't write 100 lines of code to then face 10,20 errors. Instead write just a few lines. Just enough so that it should compile. Then run the compiler. Then fix bugs. Thus is how you work efficiently as newbie. Instead of dumping a lot of code here and *misusing* this community as compiler error translation service.

Comment: Then: learn about Java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase for example. Always!

Comment: got it! thanks for the help everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the code is in this line:

String fname = **a.firstname**;

You are basically trying to access a private field when you actually want to do is:

String fname = **a.getFirstName()**;

---

The other problem is the constructor:

```
student(String la) {
        this.firstname = first;
        this.lastname = last;
        this.studentId += 1000;
    }
```

both first and last variables do not exist in this context.

Comment: That is true, I was missing the "()". However, I still get the error messages I just added on the main post.

Comment: For one thing, you can't have two top level classes in the same file. You have to separate the test from the actual code. This is actually considered a good practice regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I've added comments to better point out where the errors are that the compiler is complaining about. These are all very common compiler messages so you should take the time to understand what they are referring to and fix them. You will see them over and over again.

```
public class student { //class names start with an uppercase letter

//Fields
private static String classNumber = "264";
private static String className = "Transfiguration";
private static String instructor = "Professor McGonagall";

private int studentId;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String address;
private String city;
private String state;
private String email;

//Getters and setters

static String getClassNumber(){
    return (classNumber);
}
static String getClassName(){
    return (className);
}
static String getInstructor(){
    return (instructor);
}
static void setClassName(String name){
    className = name;
}

int getStudentId(){
    return (studentId);
}
String getFirstName(){
    return (firstname);
}
String getLastName(){
    return (lastname);
}
String getAddress(){
    return (address);
}
String getCity(){
    return (city);
}
String getState(){
    return (state);
}
String getEmail(){
    return (email);
}
void setFirstName(String first) {
    this.firstname = first;
}
void setLastName(String last) {
    this.lastname = last;
}
void setAddress(String rua) {
    this.address = rua;
}
void setCity(String cidade) {
    this.city = cidade;
}
void setEmail(Sring correio) { //You misspelled the type of the parameter
    this.email = correio;
 }
 //Contructors
student(String la) {
    this.firstname = first; //The parameter list to this constructor 
                            //only contains 'la', 'first' does not exist
    this.lastname = last; //The parameter list to this constructor 
                          //only contains 'la', 'last' does not exist
    this.studentId += 1000;
}
student(String la, int id, String first, String last, String rua, String cidade, String correio) {

    this(la);

    this.address = rua;
    this.city = cidade;
    this.email = correio;

 }

public String toString() {
    String data = "Course: " + classNumber + " " + className + 
                "\t instructor: " + instructor + 
                "\t Student Number: " + id + //id is the parameter in the 
                                             //constructor, not the private field name
                "\t Student Name: "  + firstname + " " + lastname + 
                "\t Address: " + rua + cidade + //rua and cidade are parameters in the 
                                             //constructor, not the private field names
                "\t Email: " + correio; //correio is the parameter in the 
                                        //constructor, not the private field name
    return (data);            
}

}
```

studentTest class:

```
public class studentTest { //classes start with a capital letter and belong in seprate files
public static void main (String [] args) {

    System.out.println("Course: " + student.getClassNumber() + student.getClassName());

    //Student's constructor requires 7 arguments of type String, int, String, String, String, String, String
    student a = new student("Kakashi", "Hatake", "W 69th st", "NY", "khsensei@ninja.com");
    student b = new student("Albus", "Dumbledore", "W 116th st", "NY", "princip-al@hogwarts.com" );
    student c = new student("Hyuk", "Jang", "321 Maple St", "NJ", "jh@actors.com");
    student d = new student("Michael", "Jackson", "543 thriller st", "NY", "mj@singer.com");
    student e = new student("Hamilton", "Alexander", "E 86th st", "NY", "justyouwait@broadway.com");

    String fname = a.firstname; //firstname is a private field
    System.out.println("First Name: " + fname);

    System.out.println(a.toString());
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(e);
}
}
```